# Eclipse: Git how to push after a local commit

Tags: eclipse, git, push

I sometimes realize a local commit with Eclipse and then decide to push my project but Eclipse offers me only two solutions "Commit and Push" or "Commit".

The problem is I cannot make a "commit and push" if I haven't changed anything after my "Commit".

Fair enough, I only have to change a line on my code and can push it but it seems to me like an awkward solution. Is there a better way to do so?

Answer (score 8):

You can always just open Eclipse's built-in terminal (or any other terminal app) and execute: `git push`.

On a side note: getting used to using git on the command line enables you to easily switch between different IDEs and editors without having to re-learn the respective quirks of the git integration of the *IDE de jour* every time you switch.

Answer (score 5):

In the *Package Explorer*, *Project Explorer*, etc. **right-click the project folder** and choose ***Team > Push to Upstream***.

Alternatively, you can use *Quick Access* (**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>**) and enter **`push to upstream`** (assuming a file of a Git repository is selected or opened).

For a Git main menu and Git icons in the main toolbar, in *Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective...*, in the tab *Action Set Availability* check the checkbox *Git*.